# How to solve HTTP Error: 500 (Internal Server Error) in SVN tortoisehg?

Tags: svn

I have a problem in connecting locally (within LAN) to a SVN server with SVN client TortoiseHg using HTTP protocol. I have created 2 users in the server with different passwords. While trying to clone the repository from the server PC to the client PC it shows an error like "`HTTP Error: 500 (Internal Server Error)`". I need a solution for cloning from SVN server to client.

Answer (score 0):

1. Tortoise**HG** isn't SVN-client per se (only if you have HGSubversion extension added and enabled)
2. Any GUI-tool isn't best choice for debugging problem (and 5xx errors is sign of low-level *big problem*)

Show SVN-related part of Apache's config and output of (as starting point) `svn ls URL/OF/REPO` from console